# If condition doesn't execute when match

Tags: javascript

The function is to get an array of fibonacci numbers that is lower than the given `num` parameters.

I use `while` true loop to push the followed numbers into the arrays , my break condition only stops when the sum of the last 2 number is greater than the given `num`. But when it is equal to the given `num` , the if condition still executes in some cases which lost the number number when `num` is equal to it.

```
 function fibGen(num){
   let fibo = [0,1,1],index=fibo.length-1;
   while(1){
     if((fibo[index]+fibo[index-1]) > num)break;
     else{
       fibo.push(fibo[index]+fibo[index-1]);
     }
     index++;
     console.log(fibo[index]+fibo[index-1]);

   }
   console.log(fibo);
   return fibo;
 }
```

Ex : input 70525 last number of the array should be 70525 ( 28657 + 46368 = 70525 which equals to num= 70525 ) But the loop breaks before the last number. But input 13 works

```
input : 10
output : [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 ]

input : 70525
output : [ 0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765,10946,17711,28657,46368 ] //last number missing

input : 13
output : [ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 ]
```

Why is the if case randomly failed execution ? 
I tried both chrome console and nodejs but both give the same result.

Comment: How is the last number missing in the second case? `28657 + 46368` is greater than `70525`.

Comment: your code is right. but this one `28657 + 46368 = 70525` is wrong. The result is 75025 which is greater than 70525

Comment: It was a typo on my case, the original case from my teacher is 75025

Comment: Cannot reproduce (with typo fixed) ~ http://jsfiddle.net/46xr05Lj/

Comment: @lawfulcupcake are you saying that this is solved (because you made a typo) or that you made a typo in asking the question and you're still not getting the result you expect?

Comment: @lawfulcupcake FYI, to simplify your code you should try `fibo = [0,1]` and `fibo.push(fibo.shift() + fibo[0])` and `retFibo.push(fibo[0])` or something like that

Answer (score 0):

28657 + 46368 = 75025 not 70525

Comment: Why is this getting downvotes? It clearly points out the mistake OP is making

Comment: @Phil, I guess, although the answer is or could be 100% correct, the way it's (barely) formatted brings suspect, a header like "_Here is the problem_" is not too costly, nor useless. I write this in accordance of maintaining high quality posts in SO, take care.

Comment: @MohammadKanan so leave a comment. Downvotes for correct answers hurt the community. Personally, I think this answer could have been a comment but it's still correct and in light of the apparent issue, I'm not sure this needs to be any more detailed

Comment: @Phil, I totally agree with you, (I cam here from _reviews_ not as _tag_ follower .. I never downvoted the answer).

Comment: @MohammadKanan sorry, _"leave a comment"_ wasn't directed at you. More general advice